# Animation with jQuery and HTML 5 — play sound, touch sensitive

Tags: audio, jquery-animate

I have a circle I divided it into 16 parts (4 segments in each of 4 quarters) and name each part by numbers 1,2,2,2 / 1,2,2,2 / 1,2,2,2 / 1,2,2,2.

I want to write an HTML5 and jQuery code to animate outline stork of circle by clicking on yellow part (1 piece of 16 parts is yellow; the others are gray).  The program starts animation from where the yellow part is.  The code should animate numbers around circle by changing its color and at the same time play a sound with each number.  For example, if the animation receives part 1, its color changes to orange and plays the sound "hello"; and if the animation receives number 2, it plays sound "welcome" and changes its color to orange.

After each quarter of the circle, I want to have a little delay.  For example, after playing quarter 1, the program should stop playing for 50sc and then start quarter 2 and so on.  At the end of the process, the yellow part animates with glow light and stops playing.